# How to use substring in Android Queries

Tags: android, android-contentprovider

I need to compare the last 10 digit of the phone numbers in such code:

```
String selectionClause =  ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER+ " = ?";
String[] selectionClauseArgs = { callerId };
Cursor people = resolver.query(
ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI, projections,
            selectionClause, selectionClauseArgs, null);
```

So the `selectionClause` should be like

```
String selectionClauseArgs = "substr("+CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER+",-1,10) = ?";
```

But I am not sure if I can use such `SQLLite` queries when querying `ContentProviders`.

Comment: You can find `substr` on [SQLite documentation](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_corefunc.html), so yes

Comment: I tried didnt work out. Are you sure about this solution because i did what you said before asking here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this solution, I have tested it myself and should be work.

```
//substr(string,-10, 10) take last 10 characters.
String selectionClause = "substr(" + ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER + ",-10, 10) =?";
String[] selectionClauseArgs = { callerId };
Cursor people = resolver.query(
ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI, projections,
            selectionClause, selectionClauseArgs, null);
```

and also you can use `substr(COLUMN_NAME,-10)` to take the last 10 characters.

note : For function `substr(x,y,z)`, `y` is the beginning character, if y is negative, then it count from the right of the `x`. and `z` is the number of characters taken begin from the y position.

Comment: Didn't really work and I don't really need it anymore though. I've found something else.